# Who changed the size of the transaction log?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, audit

Can I know, who and when changed size of database transation log?

Answer (score 7):

Most likely you did. Most cases database files, including transaction log, are configured for auto-growth. Auth-growth enables the file to increase its size as needed, any time is needed. The trigger for growth can be *any* activity that requires log space. The activity that triggered the growth is most cases ordinary, normal activity. The true problem is *why is the log growing*. Most times is simply lack of log truncation, see [Factors That Can Delay Log Truncation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345414.aspx). Other time it can be a single event that generates a *lot* of log and requires growth. But most often is just bad maintenance (lack of truncation).

To shrink the log now, see [How to Shrink the SQL Server log](http://rusanu.com/2012/07/27/how-to-shrink-the-sql-server-log/).

If the log was explicitly increased in size, the event is likely captured in the [default administrative trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175513.aspx).

Comment: Here's an example of using the default trace to find out about log growth: http://strictlysql.blogspot.ca/2011/01/finding-last-database-growth-date-and.html?m=1

Answer (score -1):

No. Point. This stuff is not tracked in SQL Server.

You can possibly see when (there is an event log that is available via standard reports) and see if it it was someone or auto growth (as per settings), but if it was a user, no - it is not tracked who issued the command.

That is pretty much never needed in any professional setup. You know, where you do not have clueless people do random changes. In a professional setup you have change tickets first, so you can see when a change was planned, implemented.